# how to use .getvalues with map and display the picklist value from custom setting on VF page thoghing null pointer exception

Tags: visualforce, controller, picklist, customsetting, conditional

have a custom setting called product and under that i created two fields called and other is string field BD__c. i want to display picklist value based on string matching record. my custom setting looks like

```
AAA |1,2,6,8|| common for all
BBB |1,2,6,8 || common for all
NNN|8 || only when BD is 8 
CCC| 1,2,6|| only when BD is 1,2,6
DDD|1,2,6 || only when BD is 1,2,6
I configured the custom setting as above
```

so my require is to display AAA BBB CCC and DDD when BD is 1,2 or 6,
and Display NNN,AAA,BBB when  it is 1or 2,6.
so when string value is 1,2,6,8 it should show AAA, BBB when its 8 it should show NNN, but i can see all the values even if BD__c==8
Here is my apex controller method. can someone suggest me what i am missing Or can someone just help me how to disply values on controller based on other field value. i also tried to print the value by using getvalue() but it is though null pointer exception and when i ma fetch data though. getall(0 it is display`` all the data is all the condition

```
public List < SelectOption > getTR_picklistvalue() {
    system.debug('******Start of getTR_picklistvalue');
    List < SelectOption > options = new List < SelectOption > ();
    options.add(new SelectOption('', '--Select--'));
    Map < String, picklistvalue__c > Prod = picklistvalue__c.getAll();
    List < String > keys = new List < String > (Prod.keySet());
    keys.sort();
    for (String key: keys) {
        if (Prod.get(Key).BD__c == '1,2,6,8')
            Options.add(new SelectOption(Prod.get(Key).picklistvalue__c, Prod.get(Key).Name));
        else
            Options.add(new SelectOption(Prod.get(Key).picklistvalue__c, Prod.get(Key).Name));
        //options.sort();
    }
    return options;

}//get all value ..not showing data based on condition 

`  /**   public List<SelectOption> getTR_applicationlist() {       
        system.debug('******Start of getTR_applicationlist');
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('','--Select--'));
         Map<String, applicationlist__c> Prod = applicationlist__c.getAll();
           for(String ProdValue  :Prod){
        applicationlist__c Prod1 = applicationlist__c.getValues('1,2,6,8');
           if(Prod1 != null){ 
            String applicationValue1 = Prod1.application__c;
            string applicationName1 = Prod1.Name;                    
              options.add(new SelectOption('applicationValue1','applicationName1'));}
           if(currentUser.LR_Firm_ID__c != null && currentUser.LR_Firm_ID__c == 8){              
           applicationlist__c Prod2 = applicationlist__c.getValues('8');
               String applicationValue2 = Prod2.application__c;
               string applicationName2 = Prod2.Name;
                if(Prod2 != null){               
               options.add(new SelectOption('applicationValue2','applicationName2'));}}

           else{
             applicationlist__c Prod3 = applicationlist__c.getValues('1,2,6'); 
               if(Prod3 != null){
                String applicationValue3 = Prod3.application__c;
               string applicationName3 = Prod3.Name;
                   options.add(new SelectOption('applicationValue3','applicationName3'));}
           }  }
       return options;
} **/  
// using getinstance method thoghing null pointerexception
```

Comment: You've posted this same or nearly the same question several times. When you post a new question, it is very helpful if you clarify what has changed and what *new* issue you are confronting.

Comment: Additionally, the formatting of your code, with inconsistent indentation and closing brackets piled up at the ends of lines, makes it extremely difficult to follow the logic.